# How to Setup Audit.Net?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, audit.net

I have a project that I inherited and I am trying to add [audit.net](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) to it. It is a .NET Core application that is split up too a few different projects.

I want to incorporate audit.net with EF Core and hopefully have everything in 1 audit table.

I been looking into the "[Audit.EntityFramework](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#low-level-command-interception)" extension but I not sure how to get it to work with my project and how to get if possible everything into 1 audit table.

I added the "AuditDBContext" to my DbContext via the inheritance method

```
public class MyDbContext : AuditDbContext, IApplicationDbContext
{
}
```

I then added this on top of myDbContext class

```
[AuditDbContext(Mode = AuditOptionMode.OptIn, IncludeEntityObjects = false, AuditEventType = "{database}_{context}" )]
public class MyDbContext : AuditDbContext, IApplicationDbContext
{
}
```

I then tried to use the AuditInclude on top of one of my classes and then ran the project but no audit table is created.

```
[AuditInclude]
public class TestEntity
{
}
```

I don't know if this is because the Entity is not in the same project as the MyDBContext which required me to put the nuget package in both the projects or if I missed some setup set.

Comment: You have to configure the audit data provider, by default Audit.NET will store the events as .json files on the current directory. In order to store the audit events into a SQL database, you can use either the [EntityFramework data provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#entity-framework-data-provider) or the [SQL server data provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.NET.SqlServer/README.md).

Comment: Thanks, I got it logging into the database but now trying to figure out how to add custom fields to that it's values will only be known at runtime on http request through a claim